# Anypoint Studio Launch/Deployment Issues

Tags: java-8, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Recently I downloaded Anypoint Studio 7.4 on my computer, but I've not been able to launch the same. I am running Java **Version 8 Update 181 (build 1.8.0_181-b13)** .When I try to launch, I get to the workspace selection screen and after that the Anypoint Studio 7.4 window just stays on screen frozen. Eventually, it crashes with this error:
[image]

After this, I see this long error message:
[image]

I used to run Anypoint Studio 6.6.4 projects without any issues, but now I'm not able to deploy any of my old projects. I get the following errors:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128M; support was removed in 8.0

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0

I have  found several instances of such errors in this forum, but sadly none of them have helped me so far. My Studio 6.6.4 Java preferences is shown below:
[image]

In short, I now have 2 issues (both versions of Anypoint Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed newer Java versions in your system as well? This error was common when Java 9 or 11 were installed along with 8. See [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-configure-Studio-7-1-3-on-a-Windows-machine-that-has-multiple-versions-of-Java-installed) article for details on how to fix it.

Comment: Yes I did. After seeing these issues, I installed new versions of Java as well

Answer (score 0):

The first error could be that the Java version used is 32 bits and the Studio version is 64 bits. Both should match. Be sure to use the matching version of Java and Studio. Not that if your Windows is 32 bits you will to install both as 32 bits.

PermSize and MaxPermSize are just ignored in Java 8 and cause no issues. The second problem is not finding the ApplicationDeployerclass which is strange. Is there a Mule Runtime version in the project tree?

Comment: Hi, I have Java 64 bit. Please see below:
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

And I am on Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Studio seems to be 64 bits too from the screenshot.